# invalid syntax (Issue with ' and ")

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error, syntax-highlighting

Code:

```
grb.write("            payload = f'-----------------------------325414537030329320151394843687Content-Disposition: form-data; name='file'; filename='{__file__}'Content-Type: text/plain{content}-----------------------------325414537030329320151394843687Content-Disposition: form-data; name='content'server crasher. python download: https://www.python.org/downloads-----------------------------325414537030329320151394843687Content-Disposition: form-data; name='tts'false-----------------------------325414537030329320151394843687--'\n")
```

The issue is here:

name='file';

with the first '

Comment: The code you show does not throw a SyntaxError, which "invalid syntax" should. What exactly is the problem you are asking about? Please [edit] the question to clarify why you think there is an issue here.

Comment: Hey Hype, please try to be more clear. What are you trying to do? What do you expect would happen?

Answer (score 0):

try replacing all the `'` inside `f'...'` with `\'`. The problem here is that the `'` before `file` is closing the f-string

Comment: also would it work like this? payload = f'-----------------------------325414537030329320151394843687\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"{__file__}\"\\nContent-Type: text/plain\\n\\n{content}\\n-----------------------------325414537030329320151394843687\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"content\"\\n\\nserver crasher. python download: https://www.python.org/downloads\\n-----------------------------325414537030329320151394843687\\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"tts\"\\n\\nfalse\\n-----------------------------325414537030329320151394843687--'

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately I don't know how to solve it, I do know what your error is.

This => "some text 'more' text" works because the "" and '' nest into each other.

This => "some text 'more 'more' some' text" does not work because you are putting a
'' inside of a '' and the python compiler freaks out.

Have a nice Day!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).